# Capitalize first letter of each word in a dataframe column

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, capitalization

How do you capitalize the first letter of each word in a pandas dataframe column? For example, I am trying to make the following transformation.

```
  Column1          Column1
The apple        The Apple
 the Pear   ⟶    The Pear
Green tea        Green Tea
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use [`str.title`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.title.html):

```
df.Column1 = df.Column1.str.title()
print(df.Column1)
0    The Apple
1     The Pear
2    Green Tea
Name: Column1, dtype: object
```

Another very similar method is [`str.capitalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.capitalize.html), but it uppercases only first letters:

```
df.Column1 = df.Column1.str.capitalize()
print(df.Column1)
0    The apple
1     The pear
2    Green tea
Name: Column1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

As pandas string methods are not optimized, mapping the equivalent Python string methods is often faster than pandas' `.str` methods. So for example, to capitalize the first letter of each word, the following may be used.

```py
df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].map(str.title)

  Column1          Column1
The apple        The Apple
 the Pear   ⟶    The Pear
Green TEA        Green Tea
```

---

On the other hand, if you want to capitalize only the first character in each string, then calling `upper()` only on the first character works.

```py
df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].str[:1].str.upper() + df['Column1'].str[1:]
# or 
df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].map(lambda x: x[:1].upper() + x[1:])

  Column1          Column1
The apple        The apple
 the Pear   ⟶    The Pear
Green TEA        Green TEA
```